# Windows Mobile - open file in emulator

Tags: windows, file, mobile, emulation

I am writing a C++ application for Windows Mobile and cannot find any solution to my problem. In my application I want to open a [WAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV) file. There are 2 problems for me:

1. what function shall I use to open and close a file? Is `fopen` sufficient?
2. where shall I put the WAV file on my PC's harddrive to open it from the emulator? And what directory should be given in the code?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use SndPlaySync - details [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesnative/thread/0cfd5a20-d2e4-4cb5-a70e-a9ed5dcdf46b/).
2. If you go [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa188169.aspx), there are details on launching the emulator with a shared folder through a command line option.